# Translation from English to Pig Latin

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing part of the 'PigLatin translation' program.
Here is the part I'm doing writing right now.

```
    input_str = input("Input a word: ")

    consonant_check = 0
    while input_str[int(consonant_check)] != 'a' or 'e' or 'i' or 'u':

        output_str = input_str[:int(consonant_check)] + input_str[0,int(consonant_check)] + 'ay'
        consonant_check = int(consonant_check) + 1
    else:
        print(output_str)
```

This part is supposed to check if the word input begins with a consonant. If it does, the program could remove all consonants from the beginning of the word and append them to the end of the word. Then append "ay" to the end of the word.
   By collecting information online I had some clues about how to make it happen but I think there are still something wrong with my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would approach it similar to what you intended, resulting in the code below.

In short, check the first character of a string. If it's not a vowel (`not in ['a','e','i','o','u'`]), move the character to the end of the string. Keep doing that until you hit a vowel (so 'string' becomes 'trings' then 'ringst' then 'ingstr' before breaking the loop). Once you finally hit a vowel, you leave the loop, and print the modified string + 'ay'. If the first character is a vowel, you leave the loop and print the string + 'ay'.

There's no need to set a consonant check - you're always checking the first character (0). And there's no need to have two variables - just keep modifying and replacing the original string.

```
word_string = input("Input a word: ")

while word_string[0] not in ['a','e','i','o','u']:
    word_string = word_string[1:] + word_string[0:1]

else:
    print(word_string + 'ay')
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped a lot!

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but my solution to the pig-latin problem. When learning python, I found that looking at completed examples helped a great deal.

```
word = "snake"

import string

# Create a list of vowels an consonants
vowels   = ['a','e','i','o','u','y']
vowels  += [v.upper() for v in vowels]
consonants = [x for x in string.ascii_letters if x not in vowels]

if word[0] in consonants:
    # Find the first vowel
    idx = min([word.find(v) for v in vowels if word.find(v)>0])

    # Split the word at this point and add 'ay'
    word = word[idx:] + word[:idx] + 'ay'

print(word)
# Returns "akesnay"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your logic is overall a little messed up. I would suggest tackling the problem like this.

**1.)** Check to see if the first letter is a consonant, if not, do nothing, if so, go to step 2

**2.)** Find all of the consonants in the word and store them in a list

**3.)** If it is, remove the vowels from the word, and then append all of the consonant onto the end, followed by 'ay'.

There are infinite ways to actually implement this and I think it would be a good exercise for you to try to implement it yourself, but let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: Thank you for providing a logic.

Comment: I'm trying to put the vowel checking part into a loop now.

Comment: But it keeps saying string indices must be integers, which I don't understand

Comment: @Stidgeon I think you are correct. I was reading into what he said his goal was rather than the definition of Pig Latin, which I'm not overly familiar with